# How to check if attachment is mail message?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to determine if attachment is mail message, i have a method for identifying if attachment is PDF from its first header bytes.

```
if (buffer[0] == 0x25 && buffer[1] == 0x50 && buffer[2] == 0x44 && buffer[3]== 0x46)
```

So first header bytes 37,80,68,70
I tried to check some email messages and saw same pattern 208(0xD0),207(0xCF),17(0x11),224(0xE0) for those messages. So my question, is it safe to assume I can always identify if the attachment is mail message from these header bytes or maybe there is a better way to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if the attachment extension is ".msg" (if Attachment.Type == olAttachByValue) or check the Attachment.Type property to be olEmbeddedItem in case of an embedded message attachment.

Answer (score 0):

The Attachment class from the Outlook object model provides the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865601(v=office.15).aspx) property which you need to check to determine embedded items. The [olEmbeddeditem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868693.aspx) value means the attachment is an Outlook message format file (.msg) and is a copy of the original message.